# Create file info from resources c#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have in the resources of my visual studio C# projetc a xlsx file and I want to manipulate it by `FastExcel` library (https://github.com/mrjono1/FastExcel), but, like see you in the github's page code, I have to create a `FileInfo` object and it has only one constructor that wants a file's path but only link that I have of the file is the stream that I get by this line of code:

```
test.Properties.Resources.test1
```

How do I pass throught from link to resources to path for create a FileInfo?

Comment: You don't, you must provide a file.  It is just easier to not use a resource at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write the Stream to disk and provide the file path to the FileInfo constructor. I would create a seperate utility that can accepts a Stream and returns a file path.